# How to transform in Gimp an arbitrary selected part of an image to rectangle shape?

Tags: gimp, transform

I would change the shape of this lasso selected arbitrary shape to rectangle. My garden is 24 x 42 m rectangle.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically done with the [cage tool](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-cage.html), but it doesn't care much about the selection. You put anchors along the outline of the shape(*) that you want to make square, and then drag them to a square (best to prepare the square using guides).

Result will be very dependent on how you map the anchors to the square.

(*) Which some margin, because anything which is not inside the polygon defined by the initial anchors isn't going to move.

Comment: Wow, I was searching exactly for this :)

Comment: I noticed even if I have significant margin, some parts inside the line keep remaining.

Comment: @János You may also be able to use the Warp Transform tool to fix some parts that the Cage tool can't.  It's very manual however, and works a bit like a paint brush.